# Distributing n balls into k boxes so that every box has an even number of balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, combinations

How many ways can you distribute n balls into k boxes so that every box has an even number of balls?

Well, so far I think than n must be an even number. And I know that it basically starts with a simple equation:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
where
$$x_i\equiv 0\pmod 2$$
Normally I would use a combination with repetition but since there has to be an even number of balls in every box I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:  Let $n = 2m$.  Let $x_i = 2y_i$, $1 \leq i \leq k$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k & = n\\
2y_1 + 2y_2 + 2y_3 + \cdots + 2y_k & = 2m\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + \cdots + y_k & = m
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking about doing, I've been actually editing question and I wanted to put this as my proposition.

Comment: Well, you were on the right track then.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Of course $n$ must be even. Then distribute $\frac{n}{2}$ balls over $k$ boxes (no conditions) and double the amounts in all boxes. This gives all such even distibutions and so the problem is equivalent to the $\frac{n}{2}$ over $k$ boxes problem for even $n$. For $n$ odd there are no solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was thinking.